# after upgrading 14.04 my display is locked at one resolution and I cannot change it from the GUI

Tags: ati, display, radeon, display-resolution

I recently let my 12.04 Ubuntu HTPC upgrade to 14.04 after doing so, the resolution my system's oboard ATI Radeon card will only display is 1400 X 900 to a 55inch Video 1080P display, when I was running 12.04 there were no issues with this set up at 1080P.

The system see's the ATI board, and is using the open source drivers. When I plug in a 17inch monitor I regain the ability to change the display resolution to different settings.

How can I force the resolution back to 1080P
thanks

Comment: Please edit with output 'xrandr'

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is add that resolution using `xrandr` - [this](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html) is a good guide. You would then need to add the `xrandr` configurations to a startup file, so that you'll get your desired resolution upon reboot/startup:

- Create a bash script, `xrandr.sh` for example, and place your xrandr commands into it:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
  sudo xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1920x1080_60.00
  xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
  ```
- Make the script executable with `chmod +x xrandr.sh`
- Search for "Startup Applications" in the dash, run it, and add the script as a startup application.

The commands will now run every time you log into your account.

**OR** you can go the easy way and use a program that does the above for you -  [ResolutionX.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/resolutionx)